# Glassfish server 3 start failed

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish-3

I have started to learn a web Application on Java.I have edited some code in `index.jsp`. when i run the file a error occurs which says -

```
C:\Users\MITHILA\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApp1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:683: 
Deployment error:GlassFish Server 3 Start Failed
See the server log for details.
```

I have gone to the command prompt and written `netstat -aon` & `taskkill /f /pid 460` but it says -

```
ERROR:the process with PID 460 could not be terminated.
Reason:Access is denied
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-). It seems like you are having trouble with starting the server. Did your example code work before your edit? Also, do you have permission to start the server?

Comment: sorry,I don't understand 'permission to start the server'?I think the problem is there not in code because an empty project without any editing also faces this problem.

Comment: Can you please Paste the Server location in C drive... is it in Program files, secondly can you please tell, as what OS are you using?, Scrondly, can you please update result of one TRAIL, simple, RUN the server and the try localhost on browser.

Comment: Well,I am using Windows.I tried tasklist /svc and found the service with the PID 460.then I stopped it by going Administration tool->services->that service with PID 460.Now it's running...Thnx...